# Tail call optimization (TCO) not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, safari, tail-recursion

According to [ES6 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), Safari has tail call optimization feature. Tried it and it fails just like any other browser . Am I missing something?

```js
function factorial(n, r = 1n) {
  return (n <= 1) ? r : factorial(n - 1n, n * r)
}

console.log(factorial(36000n))
```

Safari output:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: Try running your program in strict mode.

Comment: It works in strict mode!  Would you like to post your answer or I will answer myself? Hey, at least my code was flawless .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your program in strict mode.

```js
"use strict";

function factorial(n, r = 1n) {
    return n <= 1n ? r : factorial(n - 1n, n * r);
}

console.log(factorial(36000n).toString());
```

There are four conditions that need to be met in order for a function call to be considered a proper tail call.

> - The calling function is in [strict mode](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-strict-mode-code).
> - The calling function is either a normal function or an arrow function.
> - The calling function is not a generator function.
> - The return value of the called function is returned by the calling function.

Source: [ECMAScript 6 Proper Tail Calls in WebKit by Michael Saboff](https://webkit.org/blog/6240/ecmascript-6-proper-tail-calls-in-webkit/)

Comment: I tried pasting the result here to get a better look, and got the error "Too long by 147795 characters". That's a ridiculously large number that Safari blurted out after a couple of seconds (148395 digits). Too bad TCO is only possible in WebKit.